# How to Combine the two array's when the checkbox is checked

Tags: php

I have two array and two check boxes. The array values are

```
  $a={1,2,3,4,5} --->It' for first Check box
  $b={5,6,7,8,9} --->It' for Second Check box
```

When I check the first check box only I want the result is

```
 $c[0]=1,$c[1]=2,$c[2]=3,$c[3]=4,$c[4]=5
```

And I check the second check box only I want the result is

```
$c[0]=5,$c[1]=6,$c[2]=7,$c[3]=8,$c[4]=9
```

And I have check both check boxes I want the result is

```
$c[0]={1+5},$c[1]={2+6},$c[2]={3+7},$c[3]={4+8},$c[4]={5+9}
```

It's Possible?

Comment: you mean 1+5=6, `$c[0]={6}`????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `for()` loop. Please note that this code assumes both arrays are the same size:

```
$c = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++)
{ 
    $c[] = ($a[$i] + $b[$i]);
}

print_r($c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it following way

```
<?php
 $a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
 $b = array(5,6,7,8,9);
 $c = array();  //for result
   if(isset($_POST['checkbox_1'])){
     $c = $a;
   }
   else  if(isset($_POST['checkbox_2'])){
     $c = $b;
   } else if(isset($_POST['checkbox_1']) && isset($_POST['checkbox_2'])){
    if(count($a) == count($b)){
      for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i+}){
        $c[]=$a[i] + $b[i];
      }
   }
   }else{
    echo 'Error Contact Admin';
   }

?>
```

Comment: Your second `endif` statement will never execute, because either the `if()` or first `elseif()` will be true.